# The number of times a word is repeated in the text box

Tags: c#, text

How can I make the program count how often a Pre-selected word is repeated and put it in a new text box called result and this code to colors the chosen word. What should i do now?.

```
int index = 0;
string temp = richTextBox1.Text;
richTextBox1.Text = "";
richTextBox1.Text = temp;
while (index < richTextBox1.Text.LastIndexOf(word.Text))
{
    richTextBox1.Find(word.Text, index, richTextBox1.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
    index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(word.Text, index) + 1;

    result.Text = //???
```

Comment: You need to actually **count** how many times it appears, which you are not doing. Once you actually have a count, you can set the text to the count.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to set the BackColor of the words and also output the count.

```
int i = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(word.Text);
int count = 1;
while (i > -1)
{
    richTextBox1.Select(i, word.Text.Length);
    richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
    i = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(word.Text, i + 1);
    result.Text = count++.ToString();
}
```